# Undefined variable in function declaration while it is clearly defined

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I'm working on a function that will let you measure the run-time of a passed function `run-n-time`. It's not close to finished, because while writing the code, I came across a strange error. Note that I'm quite new to common lisp.

Inputting this into my sbcl-repl (version: `SBCL 1.3.1.debian`)

```
(defun run-n-time (fn times argn)
  (loop for n from 0 to times
    do (apply fn (argn n))))
```

Gives me this output (unimportant stuff removed)

```
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable ARGN is defined but never used.

; in: DEFUN RUN-N-MEASURE
;     (ARGN N)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: ARGN
```

It states that `argn` is unused **and** undefined.

I have no idea what's going on here, it's such a simple piece of code :(

Answer (score 3):

Common Lisp has separate function and value namespaces.

The form `(argn n)` uses the `argn` operator, not the variable.  You need to use `funcall` here: `(funcall argn n)`.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly? The `(argn n)` in the function body is seen by common lisp as `argn` the _operator_, while the `(fn times argn)` in the function-definition is seen as `ARGN` the _symbol_ .

So what you need to do is retrieve the _function_ `argn` from the function namespace by using `funcall` on the _symbol_ `ARGN`?

Comment: Oh and no, `argn` is meant to be a function passed to run-n-time that takes the iteration variable `n` to determine what arguments the arbitrary function `fn` takes, for flexibility reasons.

Comment: Imagine the form `(list list)`. `list` in the operator position evaluates to the standard function `list` while `list` in the operands position is just a variable. They are both variables but normal variables can evaluates to symbols. You can do `(list (funciton list))` and now the operand fetces the vartiable from the function namespace instead. `#'list` is syntactic shortcut. `(apply #'+ '(1 2 3)) ; ==> 6`. You need to do `(funcall argn n)` to call a function bound in the variable namespace. You can also use `(apply argn (list n))`

Comment: @Sylwester, thanks, I wasn't aware of the interactions with the function namespace. If you remove the last paragraph of your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Azeirah I'll leave Svante to do it :-)

Comment: @Sylwester Hehe, whoops :x

Comment: OK.  Thanks, @Sylwester.